# how to specify alignment of columns using latex in R hmisc

Tags: r, latex

I am using this:

```
latex(data, cgroup=c("sample1", "sample2"), n.cgroup=c(2,2), file="")
```

to generate a tex table.

the output looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrlrl}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{sample1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{sample2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{abs reads}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{rel reads}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{abs reads.1}&\multicolumn{1}{l}{rel reads.1}\tabularnewline
\hline
...
%the content%
...
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Question: how can change this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrlrl}
```

to something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrrrr}
```

using the latex function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `col.just` argument probably does what you want (it is difficult to guess what your data looks like).

```
library(Hmisc)
latex(head(iris,3), file="", col.just=c("r","r","r","r","r"))
```